# TeamViewer doesn't catch Alt+Tab in Linux Mint (Mate)

Tags: linux, linux-mint, teamviewer, alt-tab, mate

When I run Teamviewer on Windows, when I press Alt+Tab, TeamViewer catches it and sends it to the remote OS, which then switches its windows.

But when I'm running Teamviewer on Linux Mint (Mate) and I press Alt+Tab, I just switch from Teamviewer to another window on my host computer.

Is there a way to make Teamviewer catch the Alt+Tab key combination? Perhaps the Window manager (marco in this case) can be told to not process Alt+Tab if the current window is Teamviewer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found a solution by chance (but I've since switched to Lubuntu):

Alt+WinKey+Tab works! It's a bit cumbersome shortcut, but it's better than nothing. But I've tested it only on Lubuntu (which uses Openbox as the window manager). Still, I think it should work on MATE too.

Comment: Confirmed working on 15.10 Xubuntu teamviewered into Windows 7.

Comment: Stopped working with TeamViewer version 13.2 on ubuntu

Comment: works with TeamViewer 15.3

Answer (score 2):

From [marco's Github page](https://github.com/mate-desktop/marco):

```
 - Global keybinding defaults include:

    Alt-Tab                forward cycle window focus
    Alt-Shift-Tab          backward cycle focus
    Alt-Ctrl-Tab           forward cycle focus among panels
    Alt-Ctrl-Shift-Tab     backward cycle focus among panels
    Alt-Escape             cycle window focus without a popup thingy
    Ctrl-Alt-Left Arrow    previous workspace
    Ctrl-Alt-Right Arrow   next workspace
    Ctrl-Alt-D             minimize/unminimize all, to show desktop

   Change keybindings for example:

     gsettings set org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch_to_workspace_1 'F1'

   Also try the MATE keyboard shortcuts control panel.

   See marco.schemas for all available bindings.
```

So you could either use `gsettings` to change the shortcut for `cycle_windows` or use `dconf-editor` to do the same using a GUI. To use `dconf-editor`, run:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

The key bindings you'll need to change should be under:

```
org → mate → Marco → global-keybindings
```

Comment: This sounds like changing Alt+Tab for all windows, which is not what I need. I need to disable it for Teamviewer connection window, but keep it enabled for all other windows.

Comment: @sashoalm I have no way of testing this at the moment, but does [AutoKey](https://code.google.com/p/autokey/) help? You could [create a 'phrase'](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/26913/how-to-customize-shortcut-keys-for-any-linux-application/) that sends `<alt>+<tab>` to the window filter `TeamViewer.exe.Wine` when you press a custom shortcut (say **Shift+Alt+S**).